# Magento 2 - Multiple stores with different root category

Tags: magento2, product, category, multistore, category-products

I have created two stores as below:
Store A: Root Category = Category A
Store B: Root Category = Category B

And I added the "Catelog Product List" widget in homepage. When I switch the store to store A, it shows all the products with category A and B. I cannot find any other way to configure the filter in the admin panel. Can anyone suggest how to display different category products in different stores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue by re-indexing `magento indexer:reindex`